# Should my company upgrade from Enterprise 2017 to sql server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, upgrade

Our production server is currently running SQL Enterprise 2017.
We're paying for software assurance which means we can upgrade at any time.
Should we be looking at SQL 2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't upgrade just for the sake of upgrading. Upgrade if there are enhancements or features that you'll get meaningful benefit from.

2017 enters Extended Support later this year, but 2022 will be released this year as well. It's probably better to let 2022 come out, see how solid a release it is (are there major bugs fixed in the first few CUs?), and then consider your options between 2019 & 2022.